Problem using typewriter-effect to animate text in React
I'm trying to use the typewriter-effect library to animate text in my React app. I'm having an issue with the cursor not being hidden after the animation is complete. I tried setting cursor: '' in the Typewriter options when the animation finishes, but it doesn't work. Is there a way to hide the cursor after the animation is complete?
1.test.jsx
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import classes from "./PageStyles/Test.css"
import Typewriter from 'typewriter-effect';
import CodeString from '../UI/Components/CodeString/CodeString';

const TestPage = () => {
  const [isAnimationComplete, setIsAnimationComplete] = useState(false);

  const handleAnimationComplete = () => {
    setIsAnimationComplete(true);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <div className='test-style'>
        <CodeString 
          customText="1" 
          customCode={
            <Typewriter
              options={{

                delay: 5,
                cursor: isAnimationComplete ? '' : '|',
                onComplete: handleAnimationComplete 
              }}
              onInit={(typewriter) => {
                typewriter
                  .typeString('A simple yet powerful native javascript')
                  .pauseFor(300)
                  .deleteChars(10)
                  .typeString('<strong>JS</strong> plugin for a cool typewriter effect and ')
                  .typeString('<strong>only <span style="color: #27ae60;">5kb</span> Gzipped!</strong>')
                  .pauseFor(1000)
                  .start();
              }}
            />
          }
        />


    <CodeString 
        customText="2" 
        customCode="print"
    />

    <CodeString 
        customText="10" 
        customCode="print"
    />

    <CodeString 
        customText="10" 
        customCode="print"
    />
  </div>
</>

    );
};

export default TestPage;


CodeString.jsx
import classes from "./CodeString.css";
import TypewriterComponent from 'typewriter-effect';

const CodeString = ({ customText, customCode }) => {
    return (
        <div className='container'>
            <div className='codestrText'>{customText}</div>
            <div className='code'>{customCode}</div>
        </div>
    );
};

export default CodeString;



I tried setting cursor: '' in the Typewriter options and using the onComplete event handler, but that didn't help. I also tried to solve this problem using pure CSS. Found various ways, including using the effect of printing text without a cursor after the animation is completed. However, these approaches were not suitable for solving my problem.
